# unease at the end of polylines in map v2

Tags: android, google-maps

i have a map v2 application with ability to drawing polylines from pinpointed location to user current location fetched from gps.

i used google directions in order to get polyline strings.

after drawing got some unease at the end point of each polyline.

see screenshot from actual device :

[image]

this is my drawing codes :

```
for(int j = 0; j < allPoints.length - 1;j++) {

           if(allPoints[j] != null) {
               System.out.println("pontos " + allPoints[j]);

               List<LatLng> test = decodePoly(allPoints[j]);

               for (int i = 0; i < test.size() - 1; i++) {
                   LatLng src = test.get(i);
                   LatLng dest = test.get(i + 1);
                   try {

                       Polygon line = googleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                               .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                                       new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                               .strokeColor(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));


                   } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                       Log.e("Error", "NullPointerException onPostExecute: " + e.toString());
                   } catch (Exception e2) {
                       Log.e("Error", "Exception onPostExecute: " + e2.toString());
                   }

               }
           }

        }
```

can i put a circle after each polyline ? does it fix my problem ?

Comment: Why don't you add just one Polygon for _all_ points, instead of making multiple small lines?

Comment: it will fix the problem ? can u change my code for me please or give me some tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cheesebaron states, the best options is adding only one `Polyline`. I haven't tested it because I don't have an example of your `allPoints` data, but it could be something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < allPoints.length - 1; j++) {
    if (allPoints[j] != null) {
        List<LatLng> test = decodePoly(allPoints[j]);
        Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true).addAll(test));
    }
}
```

You can also create only one `Polyline` instead of one `Polyline` for each `allPoints[j]`:

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
for (int j = 0; j < allPoints.length - 1; j++) {
    if (allPoints[j] != null) {
        List<LatLng> test = decodePoly(allPoints[j]);
        polylineOptions.addAll(test);
    }
}
Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

Comment: it works good on drawing, but there is a strange problem, there are two lines from one point to another, see screen shot : http://voipshop.ir/newsletter/Capture+_2016-10-07-13-46-42.jpg

Comment: my full code is here but not updated :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910838/map-v2-drawed-polylines-are-not-exactly-on-the-road

Comment: This is because you are drawing a `Polygon` (closed by definition) and you may want to draw a `Polyline`. I have edited my answer

Comment: oh ! so that's the diffrence between these two. thank u so much, you taught me a lot.