# Google Maps polyline not drawing correctly

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-polyline

I'm making an app that when clicking on a marker it will open a dialog with a "Go" button, when the user press that button it show a path. I'm creating the path with the overview-polyline from google directions api, the problem is that the line is not correctly drawn, the line creates straight lines which makes the path pass over buildings like in the image:

### [image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910838/map-v2-drawed-polylines-are-not-exactly-on-the-road/39911889#39911889

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable the Google Maps Direction API form the Google Developer Console.That should give you the path along the streets.

- Go to Google Developer Console.
- Click on Library.
- Click Google Maps Directions API under Google Maps API.
- Click on ENABLE button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google maps service to get the routes.

use the dependency for maps service and util

```
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
```

Create GeoApiContext object

```
private GeoApiContext createGeoApiContext() {
        GeoApiContext geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext();
        return geoApiContext.setQueryRateLimit(5)
                .setApiKey(GOOGLE_API_KEY)
                .setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setWriteTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Create a request for the map service using DirectionResult object.
wait() method calls syncronously to the maps service.

```
 DateTime now = new DateTime();
            try {
                DirectionsResult result = DirectionsApi.newRequest(createGeoApiContext())
                        .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                        .origin(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(13.3392, 77.1140))
                        .destination(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(13.9299, 75.5681))
                        .alternatives(true)
                        .departureTime(now).await();
                addMarkersToMap(result,map);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Handle the response DirectionResult

//You can add markers to the start and end address like this

```
 private void addMarkersToMap(DirectionsResult results, GoogleMap mMap) {
        for (int i=0;i<results.routes.length;i++) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(results.routes[i].legs[0].startLocation.lat,
                                    results.routes[i].legs[0].startLocation.lng)).
                            title(results.routes[i].legs[0].startAddress));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(results.routes[i].legs[0].endLocation.lat,
                                    results.routes[i].legs[0].endLocation.lng)).
                            title(results.routes[i].legs[0].endAddress).snippet(getEndLocationTitle(results,i)));
            addPolyline(results, map, i);
        }
    }
```

//Adding polyline like this.

```
 private String getEndLocationTitle(DirectionsResult results,int i) {
        return "Time :" + results.routes[i].legs[0].duration.humanReadable +
                " Distance :" + results.routes[i].legs[0].distance.humanReadable;
    }

    private void addPolyline(DirectionsResult results, GoogleMap mMap,int i) {
        List<LatLng> decodedPath = PolyUtil.decode(results.routes[i].overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath());
        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(decodedPath).width(5));
    }
}
```

Please refer to this.
https://android.jlelse.eu/google-maps-directions-api-5b2e11dee9b0