# google maps are showing wrong and incomplete directions

Tags: android, google-maps

Sometimes getFromlocationName() method returns null and sometimes it gives values but path which is drawn is not correct. what may be the reason for this? kindly solve the problem ,Thank you.

**below is code**

```
 if((place1 != null) || (!place1.equals(" "))&& ((place2!=null)||(!place2.equals(" "))))
                {

                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                    try {
                               Boolean check=geocoder.isPresent();
                        Log.d("check:"," "+check);
                               addressList1 = geocoder.getFromLocationName(place1, 1);
                               addressList2 = geocoder.getFromLocationName(place2, 1);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("ADDRESS","address obj:"+addressList1+","+addressList2);
                    Address address1 = addressList1.get(0);
                    Address address2 = addressList2.get(0);
                    origin = new LatLng(address1.getLatitude(),address1.getLongitude());
                    destination = new LatLng(address1.getLatitude(),address2.getLongitude());
                    Log.d("LATLANG","LatLang:"+origin+","+destination);
      build_retrofit_and_get_response(mode);

                }
            }


     public void build_retrofit_and_get_response(String type) {
          Toast.makeText(this,"retrofit method called"+origin+destination,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/";

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            RetrofitMaps service = retrofit.create(RetrofitMaps.class);

            Call<Example> call = service.getDistanceDuration("metric", origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude,destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude, type);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<Example> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                    try {
                        //Remove previous line from map
                        if (line != null) {
                            line.remove();
                        }
                        // This loop will go through all the results and add marker on each location.
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getRoutes().size(); i++) {
                            String distance = response.body().getRoutes().get(i).getLegs().get(i).getDistance().getText();
                            String time = response.body().getRoutes().get(i).getLegs().get(i).getDuration().getText();
                            ShowDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:" + distance + ", Duration:" + time);
                            String encodedString = response.body().getRoutes().get(0).getOverviewPolyline().getPoints();
                            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
                            line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                    .addAll(list)
                                    .width(10)
                                    .color(Color.RED)
                                    .geodesic(true)
                            );
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
                }
            });

        }

        private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
            List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
            int lat = 0, lng = 0;

            while (index < len) {
                int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lat += dlat;

                shift = 0;
                result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lng += dlng;

                LatLng p = new LatLng( (((double) lat / 1E5)),
                        (((double) lng / 1E5) ));
                poly.add(p);
            }

            return poly;
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910838/map-v2-drawed-polylines-are-not-exactly-on-the-road/39911889#39911889

Answer (score 0):

it was beacase i was taking wrong coordinates:

```
  origin = new LatLng(address1.getLatitude(),address1.getLongitude());
  destination = new LatLng(address1.getLatitude(),address2.getLongitude());
```

correct code is:

```
  origin = new LatLng(address1.getLatitude(),address1.getLongitude());
  destination = new LatLng(address2.getLatitude(),address2.getLongitude());
```

but getting null values from getfromlocationName() of geocoder why??